How to enable git gpg signing all commits from my computer
Background: It was years ago since I reinstalled my Linux Mint, now having couple months new installation of Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon, so I do not know if my question is specific to VS Codium which is Free/Libre Open Source Software Binaries of VS Code meaning it has disabled telemetry and I assume couple other things considered telemetry/tracking-related. I decided to switch from MS VS Code to Free/Libre VS Codium along with my new OS installation.

The problem is I did not remember, how I set up (if there was anything..) git to force it sign all of my commits with my GPG key?

These 3 lines of code which I ran as ordinary user from my terminal appear to be the solution. Just to note, read the attached manual pages to fully understand and maybe tweak to your needs:

Enable GPG signing by default for every repository; more on man page:
$ git config --global commit.gpgsign true


Set user.email as your unique identifier, mandatory; more on man page:
$ git config --global user.email "info@vlastimilburian.cz"


Setting user.name is optional and not the same as your GitHub username; more on man page:
$ git config --global user.name "Vlastimil Burián"




There were a few other changes, but these above are the only git-related commands I issued. I tested it before posting and it is working fine now.

Other changes I made were IMHO not that important, I made them before changes mentioned above. Please take it for completeness:

Plus, the last thing needed IMHO is this extension, so I went ahead, and installed it:

